# PHP Query dont work

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what went wrong, but it doesn't work. It doesn't print out the result.
I tried so many solutions for the query but. Maybe someone can help me.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "dbapp";
$db = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
if(!$db) {
exit("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT id FROM datas";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
print($result);
?>
```

Comment: RTFM. It tells you *exactly* how to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the array to string. You must use `print_r()` in order to print out arrays, so modify this line of code:

```
print($result);
```

into

```
print_r($result);
```

And to get fetched rows from the database, you have to loop over the result as the following:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
print_r($row); # You can get element from $row as the following $row['id']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the query but you didn't fetch the data from database yet.

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: Your variable name is misleading. `$rows` is just one row, not multiple rows.